# Stacked chart with keys in columns

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, data-visualization, stacked-area-chart

I am trying to build a stacked area chart using some CSV data from the WHO, and it is in the following format:

```
date,governate,cases,deaths,fatalRate,attackRate,english
05/22/17,Abyan,1068,10,0.9,1.75,Abyan
05/22/17,Aden,489,12,2.5,0.51,Aden
05/22/17,Al Bayda,1498,6,0.4,1.95,Al Bayda
05/22/17,Al Dhale'e,1401,8,0.6,1.86,Al Dhale'e
05/22/17,Al-Hudaydah,1397,32,2.3,0.42,Al Hudaydah
05/22/17,Al_Jawf,189,3,1.6,0.29,Al Jawf
05/22/17,Al Mahwit,2486,34,1.4,3.27,Al Mahwit
05/22/17,Amanat Al Asimah,9216,33,0.4,2.79,Amanat Al Asimah
05/22/17,Amran,3743,45,1.2,2.45,Amran
05/22/17,Dhamar,1617,33,2,0.76,Dhamar
05/22/17,Hajjah,4664,42,0.9,2.1,Hajjah
05/22/17,Ibb,1378,37,2.7,0.45,Ibb
...
```

I have managed to nest the data, and build a line chart that shows deaths per province, over time. However, I want to show the cumulative deaths over time, which would require a stacked area chart, like this example here: https://bl.ocks.org/greencracker/e08d5e789737e91d6e73d7dcc34969bf

I have created stacked area charts before, but usually the data has the relevant keys across the top, like in the example I posted a link to, or like this data:

```
day,titanic,avatar,akira,frozen,deliverance,avengers
1,20,8,3,0,0,0
2,18,5,1,13,0,0
3,14,3,1,10,0,0
4,7,3,0,5,27,15
5,4,3,0,2,20,14
6,3,1,0,0,10,13
7,2,0,0,0,8,12
```

Formatting that data for an area stack chart simply requires me to run `d3.stack().keys(["titanic","avatar","akira","frozen","deliverance","avengers"])`

However, with this particular data format from the WHO, the relevant "keys" that I hope to sort the data by are actually all in the "governate" column. It would be as if the above data were formatted like this:

```
day,movie,value
1,titanic,20
1,avatar,8
1,akira,3
1,frozen,0
1,deliverance,0
1,avengers,0
2,titanic,18
2,avatar,5
2,akira,1
2,frozen,13
...etc
```

**How do I format the data so that it can be stacked by governate, across an x-axis of time?**

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and laziest solution is simply converting the data structure you have after `d3.csv` loading and parsing that CSV to the data structure you want, suitable to be passed to the stack generator.

In this solution, I first get rid of the unnecessary columns with a row function...

```
function(d) {
    return {
        date: d.date,
        governate: d.governate,
        deaths: +d.deaths
    }
}
```

And then I use this snippet (where `rawData` is the data parsed by `d3.csv`) to get the unique dates and all the values for those dates:

```
var data = [...new Set(rawData.map(function(d) {
    return d.date
}))].map(function(d) {
    var obj = {};
    rawData.forEach(function(e) {
        if (e.date === d) {
            obj[e.governate] = e.deaths
        }
        obj.date = d;
    })
    return obj;
})
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var csv = `date,governate,cases,deaths,fatalRate,attackRate,english
05/22/17,Abyan,1068,10,0.9,1.75,Abyan
05/22/17,Aden,489,12,2.5,0.51,Aden
05/22/17,Al Bayda,1498,6,0.4,1.95,Al Bayda
05/22/17,Al Dhale'e,1401,8,0.6,1.86,Al Dhale'e
05/22/17,Al-Hudaydah,1397,32,2.3,0.42,Al Hudaydah
05/22/17,Al_Jawf,189,3,1.6,0.29,Al Jawf
05/22/17,Al Mahwit,2486,34,1.4,3.27,Al Mahwit
05/22/17,Amanat Al Asimah,9216,33,0.4,2.79,Amanat Al Asimah
05/22/17,Amran,3743,45,1.2,2.45,Amran
05/22/17,Dhamar,1617,33,2,0.76,Dhamar
05/22/17,Hajjah,4664,42,0.9,2.1,Hajjah
05/22/17,Ibb,1378,37,2.7,0.45,Ibb
05/23/17,Abyan,1068,9,9.9,1.75,Abyan
05/23/17,Aden,489,92,9.5,0.51,Aden
05/23/17,Al Bayda,1498,9,0.4,1.95,Al Bayda
05/23/17,Al Dhale'e,1401,9,0.6,1.86,Al Dhale'e
05/23/17,Al-Hudaydah,1397,92,2.3,0.42,Al Hudaydah
05/23/17,Al_Jawf,189,9,1.6,0.29,Al Jawf
05/23/17,Al Mahwit,2486,94,1.4,3.27,Al Mahwit
05/23/17,Amanat Al Asimah,9216,93,0.4,2.79,Amanat Al Asimah
05/23/17,Amran,3743,95,1.2,2.45,Amran
05/23/17,Dhamar,1617,93,2,0.76,Dhamar
05/23/17,Hajjah,4664,92,0.9,2.1,Hajjah
05/23/17,Ibb,1378,97,2.7,0.45,Ibb`;

var rawData = d3.csvParse(csv, function(d) {
  return {
    date: d.date,
    governate: d.governate,
    deaths: +d.deaths
  }
});

var data = [...new Set(rawData.map(function(d) {
  return d.date
}))].map(function(d) {
  var obj = {};
  rawData.forEach(function(e) {
    if (e.date === d) {
      obj[e.governate] = e.deaths
    }
    obj.date = d;
  })
  return obj;
})

console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Now, with this `data` array structure, you can use your stack generator (`d3.stack()`).

Comment: PS: My solution does nested loops, which I admit is not the most fast code. If you turn this into a pure JS question, removing the other tags and asking only how to manipulate the array to the desired outcome, you'll get more answers from the JS specialists.

Comment: Thanks Gerardo. This works, but in reality my csv is a large external file, and I'd rather not post it in the HTML. Do you know how I could separately pull it in, but stick with this method?

Comment: What do you mean by *"and I'd rather not post it in the HTML"*?